# How to define two ng-click functions in a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

Here's my code in the template.

```
    <button ng-click="{{backFunction}}" ng-show="{{backShow}}"> Back </button>
    <button ng-click="{{nextFunction}}" ng-show="{{nextShow}}"> Next </button>
```

Directive Code

```
directive('navigationButtons', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        templateUrl : 'angular/app/partials/navigationButtons.html',
        scope: {
            backFunction: '@',
            backShow: '@',
            nextFunction: '@',
            nextShow: '@'
        }

        };
})
```

View Code (where I'm using the directive)

```
<navigation-buttons nextFunction="a.active=true" nextShow="true" backFunction="b.active=false" backShow="true"></navigation-buttons>
```

It is showing error as `Syntax Error: Token 'nextFunction' is unexpected`

Comment: You are defining to isolated scope with '@' while one directive can have one isolated scope only I think

Comment: @aokaddaoc false, you can have more than one isolated scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errors in your code, first of all, in your template, you have change the camel case names for dash separated, and remove the curly brackets

```
<button ng-click="backFunction()" ng-show="backShow"> Back </button>
<button ng-click="nextFunction()" ng-show="nextShow"> Next </button>
```

Now in your directive replace the scope isolations:

```
directive('navigationButtons', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    templateUrl : 'angular/app/partials/navigationButtons.html',
    scope: {
        backFunction: '&',
        backShow: '@',
        nextFunction: '&',
        nextShow: '@'
    }
};
```

I created a jsfiddle with your code working: http://jsfiddle.net/v7V6y/

Best!

Comment: when to use / not to use `{{}}` ?

Comment: It depends of the directive that you are using.
If the directive expects a string, you need to use {{ var }},
but if your directive expects an expression, you should not use {{ }}.

For example: The directives ngClick, ngShow, ngIf expect an expression, but the directive ngSrc expects a string.

Answer (score 2):

you should receive functions with & and not @

also receive the boolean for show/hide with = if you need two way binding & dont want to setup $watch/$observe

```
directive('navigationButtons', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        templateUrl : 'angular/app/partials/navigationButtons.html',
        scope: {
            backFunction: '&',
            backShow: '=',
            nextFunction: '&',
            nextShow: '='
        }

        };
})
```

check this link on [passing functions to directive](http://blog-it.hypoport.de/2013/11/06/passing-functions-to-angularjs-directives/)

**EDIT**

also check out this [great article](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html) on directives

Comment: I made those changes, but still it is showing the same error. :-(

Comment: can you please setup the plunker, i will try to resolve the issues